Error connecting Firebase to Android Studio Porject
I tried to link the connection firebase to android studio in my app. However, i can't seem to run the application even though there is no coding error. I'll provide the code below.
below is the java code.
package com.example.rwn;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class ReportActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText editTextName, editTextBinLocation, editTextProblem;
    private Button buttonSubmit;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_report);

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });

        // Initialize Firebase Database
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("reports");

        // Initialize UI elements
        editTextName = findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        editTextBinLocation = findViewById(R.id.editTextBinLocation);
        editTextProblem = findViewById(R.id.editTextProblem);
        buttonSubmit = findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);

        // Set onClick listener for the submit button
        buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener(v -> submitReport());
    }

    private void submitReport() {
        String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
        String binLocation = editTextBinLocation.getText().toString().trim();
        String problem = editTextProblem.getText().toString().trim();

        if (name.isEmpty() || binLocation.isEmpty() || problem.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        String id = databaseReference.push().getKey();
        Report report = new Report(id, name, binLocation, problem);

        assert id != null;
        databaseReference.child(id).setValue(report)
                .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Report submitted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // Clear fields after submission
                    editTextName.setText("");
                    editTextBinLocation.setText("");
                    editTextProblem.setText("");
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to submit report", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
    }
}


package com.example.rwn;

public class Report {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String binLocation;
    private String problem;

    public Report() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(Report.class)
    }

    public Report(String id, String name, String binLocation, String problem) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.binLocation = binLocation;
        this.problem = problem;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getBinLocation() {
        return binLocation;
    }

    public String getProblem() {
        return problem;
    }
}


let me know if i need to provide more context/code
I modified the gradle code to suit my project needs. I also added a line to connect to the internet in the manifest.xml file below is the gradle code.
(project level)
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0") // Use the latest stable version
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10")
    }
}

plugins {
    // Use the latest stable version of the Android Application plugin and Google Services plugin
    id("com.android.application") version "8.0.0" apply false
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.3.10" apply false
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}


(app level)
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.rwn"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.rwn"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.0.0"))
    implementation("androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity:1.4.0")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database")
    implementation("com.github.denzcoskun:ImageSlideShow:0.0.6")
    implementation("com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0")
}



If there's no error message, it's gonna be hard to help without some additional information. I recommend debugging the problem locally, and editing your question to share the results. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Can you please elaborate more about your problem, because your code seem to be fine maybe there is some problem with IDE.
Here are some solutions that might help you:

Invalidate Cache (File > Invalidate Cache)
Use the latest version of Android Studio.
Make sure that you have entered correct name of your database reference.
Make sure that Firebase Database rules are Valid, if not the Firebase will deny your request.

